# Importing CSV data and splitting correctly

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, neural-network

I'm trying to create a neural network using NumPy, but im having trouble with importing and splitting my CSV file. When I run my code it seems to believe I want all of my rows, when I only want the 70% that I split in my code below. my data is 470 rows in total but I want the 329 value which is 70%.

not sure if the way ive indexed my code to split my x/y values has messed it up maybe. when I print my 'trainingdata' before I split to x/y it presents 329 which is the correct value. 'trainingdata' is only ever used in this section of code also which means its not a later function issue I believe.

```
dataset = pd.read_csv(('data.csv'), names = header_list)
trainingdata = dataset.sample(frac=0.7)
testingdata = dataset.drop(trainingdata.index)

X = trainingdata.iloc[:,1:].to_numpy().astype('float32')
Y = trainingdata.iloc[:,0].to_numpy().reshape(-1, 1).astype('float32')
print(Y.shape)
print(X.shape)
```

output message = ValueError: Shape of passed values is (329, 1), indices imply (470, 1)

EDIT =

```
# convert output to
predicted_output = pd.DataFrame(
    predicted_output,
    columns=["prediction"],
    index=df.index)
```

sorry for the confusion. Basically I need to call my split 70/30 dataframe in the code above, but when I try to call it doesnt work as I dont know how to call a split dataframe like this. Above is when I call the 'pre-split' dataframe (pd.Dataframe) which works fine, but when I try and call 'testingdata' (data that is split 70/30), it says as its a NumPy array this wont work.

I'm not sure how to convert my 'trainingdata' array into something callable so that it usable by the function above. Is there specific syntax for this?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the full traceback of the error, as that includes important diagnostic information

Comment: after reviewing the error I noticed I was calling 'pd.dataframe' further on in my code which would give me the full list of 470. Do you know how I would call my trainingdata instead? when i try to call it, it says it cannot accept it due to it being a DataFrame. thanks if you can give me any help

Comment: " I noticed I was calling 'pd.dataframe' further on in my code"...that's not nearly enough detail to be able to meaningfully answer. If you [edit] your question to include a [mcve] showing the relevant line of code, we might be able to understand and help